# titanium app no longer connects to facebook

Tags: facebook, appcelerator

I was until the last two weeks able to use the  following code to sign into facebook and publish to my feed (or wall, or whatever they've decided to call it):

```
fb.appid = ID; 

fb.permissions = ['publish_actions']; //nee publish_stream
fb.addEventListener("login", secondNamedFunction = function(e){
    fb.removeEventListener("login", secondNamedFunction);
    loginEventFunction(e, handleSuccessSend, handleFailSend, handleCancelSend);
});
fb.authorize();
```

however, yesterday when i attempted to do this it didn't work. i went to the sign-in page, entered my username and password, hit "Log In", and the loading graphic appeared. And nothing else happened.

I tried this several times - after around a minute the loading graphic would go away, and I would be back on the Log In page, needing to enter my username and password.

I know I put my app into "review" on facebook (which, for the record, I think is not a good thing to ask developers to do, also the review questions are confusing). However, I am listed as an admin for the app itself, so I would not have thought that this would be an issue.

No error code was sent back, I really think the request just hung. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

OH

You cannot connect to facebook on nexus 4 on 4.4.4. kitkat over a wifi connection. I don't know if this affects all nexus 4 kitkats, or just some.

Turning off the wifi and connecting over my carrier yields a successful connection. Two weeks ago we'd just moved apartment, so I didn't have wifi setup!